# Conditional variance and mean

Tags: statistics

The random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the following distribution.
$$\begin{array}{lr|rrr|l}
&&&Y\\
&f(x,y)&0&1&2&f(x)\\ \hline
&0&1/6&2/9&1/36&\\
X&1&1/3&1/6&0\\
&2&1/12&0&0\\ 
\hline
&f(y)&&&&1
\end{array}$$

**Find the conditional variance of $Y$ given $X=1$.**

The marginal of $Y$ given $X=1$ is of course $\dfrac{1}{2}$. So what I did first was to calculate the probabilities

- $P(Y=0 | X=1)=(1/3)/(1/2)= 2/3$
- $P(Y=1 | X=1)=1/3$
- $P(Y=2 | X=1)=0$

Thus $$E(Y |X=1)= 0(2/3) +1(1/3)+2(0)=1/3$$ and $$E(Y^2 | X=1)= 0^2(2/3)+1^2(1/3)+4^2(0)=1/3$$

So then the conditional variance of $Y$ given $X=1$ is $$\text{Var}(Y|X=1)=(1/3)-(1/3)^2$$

But I am not sure if my process is correct.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

As a check, given $X=1$, you could say $Y$ is a [Bernoulli random variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) with parameter $p=\frac13$.  The mean of a Bernoulli random variable is $p$ and its variance is $p(1-p)$, as you have found in this particular case.